# como puedo crear multiples formularios de una misma clase en un template de django 4.3

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

**mi problema es el siguiente:
tengo un form que guarda los datos de una presentacion artistica(modelo_M2) y a esa presentacion artistica tengo que asociarle la distribucion de los pagos a los diferentes artistas que participaron necesito crear multiples formularios de pago en  un mismo templete en base a la cantidad de artistas que tenga la unidad artistica osea un modelo de pago por cada artista de la unidad artistica**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Modelo_M2, Pago
from common.models import Unidad_Artistica, Cliente, Zona_Pago, Comercial


class modelo_M2_form(forms.ModelForm):
        id_m1 = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        id_m2 = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        unidad_artistica = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Unidad_Artistica.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        comercial = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Comercial.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        realizado = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        captado = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        cliente = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cliente.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        presentaciones = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=2, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        zona_pago = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Zona_Pago.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        total = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        empresario = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'value': '0'}))
        gastos = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'value': '0'}))
        centro = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        total_unidad_artistica = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

        class Meta:
            model = Modelo_M2
            fields = '__all__'


class Pago_form(forms.ModelForm):
    ci = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    nombre_apellido = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    importe = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    porciento_onat = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    descuento_onat = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'value': '5', 'disable': 'true'}))
    ganado = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Pago
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Porque no trabajas con formularios aparte? uno para el modelo_M2 y otro para pago_Form cuando crees el pago_form le pasas la cantidad que te permita agregar y lo controlas por JS? asimismo puedes permitir que el trabajo no se quede colgado o se pierda por completo si hay un refresh del sitio.

Comment: el problema es que tengo que crear varios pagos distribuir el dinero entre los artistas de la unidad artistica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola a todos la respuesta al problema la encontre usando formset() de la clase Form de django gracias a los que se preocuparon